# How to block a person's number and send automatic responses to its call/text attempts?

Tags: call-screening, sms-blocking

I want to put someone on a blacklist so I can't see when he calls me or what messages he sends to me. *This is the easy part*.

But I also want some custom text messages to be automatically sent to him if he tries to call/text me, like "Leimi put you on his blacklist, you really should stop trying". *This is the not so easy part?*

Do you know if this is possible by default in recent Android versions, via an application or even a custom ROM? Thanks.

Comment: There are a several apps on the Market that claims to be able to do this Auto Reply for blocked numbers, what have you tried?

Comment: At the time where I just wanted to block unknown numbers I tried several apps (don't really remember what) but only one worked well: Call Filter. Didn't remember seeing apps with an auto reply feature. Now that you're mentionning it, I indeed see a couple of apps that seem to do exactly what I want T_T Don't know how I missed them, thanks. I guess I'll test and come back here with the one I choose.

Comment: I was going to suggest using Google Voice, but I see you're in France. The problem with your proposed solution is that by sending a custom message like that all you're doing is confirming that your number still works. All your tormentor need do is find a different number from which to call you and your block will be for naught.

Comment: Yeah I'm in France :) In this particular case I actually don't mind if the blocked person knows my number still works. The purpose is actually to warn the person that it's useless to keep trying contacting me on my phone.

Comment: Well... Tested "Blacklist", "Ultimate Call Blocker Free", "Call Blocker 2.0", "Easy Filter"... none actually worked.